# Advice needed on EPX and sizing for UWP app on different devices

Tags: win-universal-app

I'm really trying to get my head around how sizing is meant to work on different devices (and setting control widths as a result) in terms of Effective Pixels and can't seem to find the answer to what must be a really simple question.

I have this code that gives me the EPX of the current window/screen...

```
private void GetViewSize()
{
    ApplicationView view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    Rect rect = view.VisibleBounds;
}
```

When I call the method on my Dell monitor (when the app is fullscreen)  I get 1920x1080 back which is correct; on my Surface Pro 4 (also fullscreen) I get 2736x1824 which is also correct.  If I then resize the app on either device it always gives me the right size - in other words, the actual size as dictated by the resolution of the device.

All good so far - but when I deploy my app to either the 6" 1080p emulator or my Lumia 1520 (which is also 1080w x 1920h) and call this method the VisibleBounds reports the width as 432 and the height as 744 which I do not understand.... how is this worked out?  432 is not a factor of 1080 and 744 is not a factor of 1920 and these sizes don't even reflect the standard "break sizes" MS recommends for scaling and sizing - so what am I missing?

I'm sure there is an absolutely simple explanation but I have not found anything that really explains how EPX works across devices and how to scale my controls etc so they all look the same width and size on any device.

Comment: We are investigate on this problem and trying to find a official explanation about this. By the way, why you need this API? Maybe we can try to solve this problem using other methods.

Comment: Grace, are you saying this is a known bug? Also, what do you mean when you say "why you need this API?"  This is not an API - I am just trying to size certain controls (HubSections mainly) so that when I am on a mobile device (or a screen of less than certain pixels) each HubSection in my Hub takes up the width of the screen, whereas on devices bigger than a certain size, the Hubsection width is the total width of the screen / 3  (as I have 3 HubSections in my Hub).  So on a smaller device you'll swipe between sections and on a larger device you'll see all 3 Hubsections.

Comment: No, I can't say this is a bug for now, Next Monday I will continue on this case. Are you trying to use Hub control and make the layout adaptive for different sizes of devices?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do - as I said above, on a phone or smaller screen each hubsection would take up the whole screen and you'd swipe to see the others (like the Pivot on WP8) but on a larger screen where the 3 hubsections can fit they are all shown.

The point here is not what I'm trying to do, it's the fact I get such strange screen resolution for a 1080p phone.... I just want to understand why I get these numbers and how EPX is meant to work across devices.